# Preservation of theoreticity under union

Tags: logic

I'm working through various presentations of Henkin-style completeness proofs for first-order logic, where the underlying first-order language need not be countable. I understand most of the technicalities without any problems, but for one minor point.

Let a *theory* in a first-order language L be a set of L-sentences that is closed under derivability. Let a theory be *consistent*, if no contradiction can be derived from it. Finally let a theory be *maximally consistent*, if it is consistent and it is identical to each of its consistent supersets.

Now in the course of proving Lindenbaum's lemma (each consistent theory is contained in a maximally consistent theory) the usual move is to use the followong claim:  If T is a set of theories in L linearly ordered by inclusion, then T's union (the set of those things that are members of some member of T) is a theory.

I'm not sure how to prove this claim. Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let U be the union of T. Any derivation U ⊢ A uses a finite number of assumptions from U. Since the set T of theories is linearly ordered by inclusion, there is a theory T' ∈ T containing all these assumptions, so that T' ⊢ A. Since T' is a theory, A ≠ ⊥. Also since T' is a theory, A ∈ T', which gives A ∈ U. Thus U is a consistent and closed under derivations. Thus U is a theory.

EDIT: Above I assumed that a theory is consistent, which the question did not require. Allowing inconsistent theories, the proof still works (with the obvious changes).